# The code does not send a HTTP request

Tags: javascript, html, http, xmlhttprequest

I want to send an HTTP request from an HTML page when the user presses the button "Send JSON". The client implementation is the following one:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Page</div>            
        <p>Click the button below to send json</p>
        <button type="button" onclick="sendJson()">Send file</button>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>            
            function sendJson()
            {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
                xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:9000/test");
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                var data = JSON.stringify({"email": "hey@mail.com", "password": "101010"});
                xmlhttp.send(data);
            }
        </script>
    </body> </html>
```

The http://localhost:9000/test is the URL where the server runs.

The problem with this code is that it doesn't send an HTTP request. What is the problem with this code?

Comment: can you make a js fiddle with your code?

Comment: It does send the request. What do you see in the console?

Comment: Yes, I can make a js fiddle and the js works but it doesn't send an Http request